# How do I link src (HTML) from a host and not from a directory in VSCode?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble with previewing images and such in VSCode, which limits my ability to edit HTML properly in VSCode.

So instead of writing an entire URL, can I just "link" the DNS as a folder?

For example, instead of writing something like

```
src="www.site.com/file/pic.jpg"
```

Can I just write something like

```
src=file/pic.jpg
```

with any specific command in between? like a ref?

I've tried something like  but I really haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: `file/pic.jpg` means that there is a child folder of the folder where your html is, that is called `file` and inside it there is a file named `pic.jpg`. If this is your case everything is fine. but there is no need to specify the domain (and in that case you have to add the protocol)